# Is $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N\times N},f(x)=(x,x)$ onto?

Tags: functions

Is $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N\times N},f(x)=(x,x)$ onto?

I am not sure how to tell. Say $b\in N\times N$ this means the codomain is all the different combinations of the natural numbers.

But the domain is only the natural numbers multiplied, like $3\times 7$

Comment: Hint: consider (0,1)

Comment: Is there an $n$ such that $f(n)=(3,14)$?

Comment: Oh I see there cannot be a n for (3,14) because n is a single natural number that when multiplied by itself will make one natural number. Not a pair is that the reason.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez There is no multiplication in this scenario. The $\times$ in $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ denotes the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the two sets.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez In André's comment, $(3,14)$ means the pair: first element $3$, second element $14$.

Comment: I see so it means the pair cannot be in the range. Because N in the domain is a single natural and not two different naturals.

Comment: What is $\left(x,x\right)$? is it an open interval? The notation is bad..

Comment: The notation is not bad, because (*,*) is standard notation for an element of a Cartesian product, which we know it has to be by context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of pairs of natural numbers. That is, 
$$
\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} = \{ (a,b) \mid a, b \in \mathbb{N} \}.
$$
It does *not* denote the set of products of numbers in $\mathbb{N}$.

Secondly, the definition of "onto" is that all elements of the codomain are in the range. That is, for any $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ it is possible for $f(x) = (a,b)$ for some $x$.

If $a \neq b$, this is not possible, so it's not onto.